Edge can not visit Non-SSL url properly
When several months ago after "Edge" browser on my Win10 X64 machine updated itself to latest version, I began to meet a problem when visiting some websites in my favorites, at first I could not find  the reason, after many tries I think I have found the problem, let me explain it in detail since it is a little bit complicated:

the website only support non-ssl , it means the url is like http:// not https://
I have put the url into my favorites in edge, it seems it will auto put https:// in the url, I will manually change it back to http:// and save favorites
I click favorites in my edge, the browser will automatically visit https:// url although I have changed it to http:// , so I can not visit this site
If I manually put http:// url in the address bar, it seems if this url is in my favorites, it will still be changed to https://(I do not know why?), so I can not visit this site too
So If I want to visit this site properly, the only I can do is delete this url in my favorites and manually input http:// url in address bar(this time it will not auto change to https just because I deleted it in favorites?)

I have not done any special config in my edge, and before updates several months ago, the problem not exist, so how to deal with this problem, Can I do some config to make me visit this site just by click my favorites? Thanks

Seems like auto-https is enabled. Tot turn it off (or on), see https://www.makeuseof.com/enable-automatic-https-microsoft-edge/, https://www.makeuseof.com/enable-automatic-https-microsoft-edge/ . If that works, please let us know to make it an answer.

Edge, Chrome, and honestly every browser based of Chromium have for years defaulted to https, how old was the version, you originally had installed? By years it’s likely closer to 5, which doesn’t make sense for Edge, since Chromium Edge isn’t even 3 years old yet.

@DrMoishePippik , my current edge vesion is 124.0.2478.67 x64 , I can not find the configuration of "Automatically switch to more secure connections with Automatic HTTPS" and I can not find "edge://flags/#edge-automatic-https" option either, so maybe this option can not be changed currently?

@Ramhound my current edge vesion is 124.0.2478.67 x64, I can not figure out which version the problem not exist , but it should be several months ago not years ago, after that update, the problem arise

edge-automatic-https is likely an older flag that was discontinued since it became the default behavior. Given this 2021 article I suspect was retired more than a year ago.

@Ramhound, then how to deal with this issue? it is strange because even I manually type http not https in addressbar or modify favorites' url to http , edge still make https visit, but if no favorites saved, you can manually type http and visit as http, so this is a bug?
